# What is the correct place to set the Default Namespace for a Multiple Module project created with Phalcon DevTools?

Tags: phalcon

I just started looking about Phalcon this week, I'm trying to create a multiple module application with the dev tools.

The result of running `phalcon project <name> multiple` only creates one module ('frontend') and it works fine. However, when I add a second module (by copying the frontend one and changing the namespace to \Backend , I couldn't get to the Backend\IndexController class.

After reading the doc page about mutiple module applications and looking at the samples (https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/tree/master/multiple and https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/tree/master/multiple-volt) and an old question on the Google group (sorry, can't post more than 2 links since I'm new on StackOverflow), I've ended commenting this this line on the services.php file:

```
$router->setDefaultNamespace("MyL\Frontend\Controllers"); //project name is MyL
```

and adding the following on the setServices of my backend/Module.php file:

```
$di->set('dispatcher', function() {
                $dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
                $dispatcher->setDefaultNamespace("MyL\Backend\Controllers");
                return $dispatcher;
            });
```

and the something similar on the frontend/Module.php

It works with these modifications, but my question is: is this the best way to do it, or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your modules in your app like so:

```
$app = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application();

$app->registerModules(
    [
        'frontend' => [
            'className' => 'MyL\Frontend\Controllers',
            'path'      => '../apps/frontend/Module.php'
         ],
        'backend'  => [
            'className' => 'MyL\Backend\Controllers',
            'path'      => '../apps/backend/Module.php'
         ],
    ]
);
```

Make sure that you have the Module.php ready also for each module

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for the delay. I had the modules set up like what you describe, and the Module.php for each module was just like the dev tools generate it, but it wouldn't let me get to the backend Controllers.

Comment: You are probably missing the route, or the routes are misconfigured.

Comment: @SinisaValentic could you explain which route I might be missing, and how and where to configure it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to split frontend and backend in Phalcon project without modules:
https://github.com/borzov/phalcon-templates